# How to rewrite this function in one line?

Tags: function, iterator, julia, one-liner

I have the following lines of code:

```
f((k,v)) = Symbol(k) => Symbol(v)
Dict(Iterators.map(f, pairs(names)))
```

And I want to write it in a single line. I tried this:

```
Dict(Iterators.map((k,v) -> Symbol(k) => Symbol(v), pairs(names)))
```

But it throws Method Error:

```
MethodError: no method matching (::var"#13#14")(::Pair{Symbol, String})
```

Is it possible to write this in a single line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want this:

```
Dict(Iterators.map(((k,v),) -> Symbol(k) => Symbol(v), pairs(names)))
```

(note the comma after `(k,v)` which forces destruction of the first argument to the anonymous function into two eleements)

Answer (score 4):

What about

```
Dict(Symbol(k)=>Symbol(v) for (k, v) in pairs(names))
```

?

Comment: This would be better, but I understood that OP had a problem with correct writing of method signatures.

Comment: This looks cleaner. Thanks, both of you! @BogumiłKamiński